# In Angular, how can is use @input from a third party directive to pass value from children back to the directive?

Tags: angular

I have a library, let's call it `books` and multiple applications need to use `books`. I also need to have standardized classes, layout, and make sure `books` is always up to date. Instead of having to up date multiple applications, I'm making a "middle man" library called `my-books` so instead of `<books [options] (events)></books>` the dev will do `<my-books [options] (events)></my-books>` and I can spit out the standardized structures across all apps. Plus when `books` is updated I can updated in my library, test, and push the update to all apps.

That being said, I want the devs to have access to all `@Input` and `@Output` instances for `books`. They'd pass the same values and watch for the same events on my library (this insures the documentation for `books` is still valid).

This way I don't have to attempt to account for all `@Input` and `@Output` instances in `books`.

I assume `export class MyBooksComponent extends BooksDirective` would allow for this. I placed `MyBooksComponent` in the `app.module.ts` in the `declarations` and `exports` but I get an error:

`is listed in the declarations of the NgModule 'AppModule', but is not a directive, a component, or a pipe.`

Is there a better way to do this or am I just missing a secret sauce?

Answer (score 0):

> I assume `export class MyBooksComponent extends BooksDirective` would allow for this.

You are almost there. Angular tried to tell you that `MyBooksComponent` isn't a directive nor a component because Angular uses the decorators as its meta data to do all the groundwork.

You need to use the `decorator` such as `@Directive({...})` or `@Component({...})`.

Here is a quick example:

```js
@Directive({
  selector: '[appMyBook]',
  standalone: true
})
export class MyBookDirective extends BookDirective {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

}
```

When you `extends` a directive, all of the parent's `@Input` and `@Output` are accessible to the consumers via the child directive. I created a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hjufiv?file=src%2Fmy-book.directive.ts) to show the behavior.